# What are the tools missing in the 10.1 ArcToolBox compared to the 10.2

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox

I want to downgrade my ArcGIS 10.2 to 10.1 hoping it would be less slow and buggy but I just won't afford to have any toolsets missing in the 10.1

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to 10.7 instead? There are all the same tools as previous versions, plus new ones. And in my experience 10.5-10.7 have all been much less buggy than either 10.2 or 10.1 (ESPECIALLY 10.1). 10.1 and 10.2 are also both officially retired by ESRI, and are no longer even in Mature Support.

Comment: In my experience 10.2.0 was a significant improvement over 10.1sp1, and 10.2.1 and 10.2.2 were improvements over 10.2.0 and 10.2.1, respectively. I fear you're going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at the [What's new in 10.2 document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/pdf/whats_new_in_arcgis.pdf). The items listed in here will **not** exist in the previous, 10.1 version.